# connection reset by peer error with nginx, unicorn and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

This is the output I'm seeing in my nginx error log:

```
013/11/10 09:40:38 [error] 20439#0: *1021 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: <server ip>, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http:/some ip address:80/", host: "some id address"
```

Here is the nginx.conf file contents:

```
user  www-user;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
error_log  /srv/app.myserver.com/current/log/nginx-error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 30000;

events {
    worker_connections  10000;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    access_log  /srv/app.myserver.com/current/log/nginx-access.log main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/myserver.conf;
}
```

---

And here is the contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/myserver.conf:

```
upstream myserver {
  # This is the socket we configured in unicorn.rb
  server unix:/srv/app.myserver.com/current/tmp/myserver.sock
  fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  #client_max_body_size 4G;
  server_name app.myserver.com;

  #keepalive_timeout 5;

  # Location of our static files
  root /srv/app.myserver.com/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @myserver;

  location @myserver {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://myserver;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

---

Finally, here's the contents of my config/unicorn.rb file with comments stripped out to save space here:

```
worker_processes 4

user "www-user", "www-user"


root = "/srv/app.myserver.com/current/"
working_directory root

# QUESTION HERE: should this be considered relative to working_directory or from filesystem root?
listen "/tmp/myserver.sock", :backlog => 64
listen 8080, :tcp_nopush => true
listen 80, :tcp_nopush => true

timeout 30

pid "/srv/app.myserver.com/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
```

I'm using Capistrano to deploy and I've made sure that the tmp dir is there and there's a myserver.sock file in there.

And finally, when I do nginx -V I get this list of configuration flags:

```
--prefix=/etc/nginx 
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx 
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log 
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log 
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid 
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock 
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp 
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp 
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp 
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp 
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp 
--user=nginx 
--group=nginx 
--with-http_ssl_module 
--with-http_realip_module 
--with-http_addition_module 
--with-http_sub_module 
--with-http_dav_module 
--with-http_flv_module 
--with-http_mp4_module 
--with-http_gunzip_module 
--with-http_gzip_static_module 
--with-http_random_index_module 
--with-http_secure_link_module 
--with-http_stub_status_module 
--with-mail 
--with-mail_ssl_module 
--with-file-aio 
--with-ipv6 
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector 
--param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables'
```

I don't see anything in there calling out the upstream module. Could that be my problem?

This is my first pass at using nginx and unicorn so I'm kind of missing lots of context still...

if you need further information, let me know...

Comment: it might be helpful to post your unicorn and nginx configuration. wouldn't it?

Comment: yes. I'll add that. I was hoping someone might recognize the general error and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to try:

In your nginx config, set your upstream server to use `localhost:<unicorn-port>` instead of the socket.  Example:

```
upstream myserver {
  server localhost:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Since nginx is your web server, I'd remove `listen 80, :tcp_nopush => true` from your `unicorn.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks all for the ideas. I figured this out and I was barking up the wrong tree entirely. The problem was that unicorn was failing to start. This was because one of our helpers was a class, not a module and while thin and webrick allow this, Unicorn was having kittens. I had a few other trivial things but once I was able to start unicorn things worked fine. At the time of this post I didn't realize I had to start unicorn--my head was firmly up my...well, you get the picture.

Again, thanks for the ideas in answers and comments. I appreciate it greatly.

Error exists between Keyboard and Chair. :P